# How to test Python function which writes to file

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a Python function that takes a list as an argument and writes it to a file:

```
def write_file(a):
    try:
        f = open('testfile', 'w')
        for i in a:
            f.write(str(i))

    finally:
        f.close()
```

How do I test this function ?

```
def test_write_file(self):
    a = [1,2,3]
    #what next ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the `write_file` function and check whether `testfile` is created with expected content.

```
def test_write_file(self):
    a = [1,2,3]
    write_file(a)
    with open('testfile') as f:
        assert f.read() == '123' # Replace this line with the method
                                 #   provided by your testing framework.
```

If you don't want test case write to actual filesystem, use something like [`mock.mock_open`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open).

Answer (score 0):

First solution: rewrite you function to accept a writable file-like object. You can then pass a StringIO instead and test the StringIO's value after the call.

Second solution: use some mock library that let you patch builtins.